# Javascript, design function to reference itself

Tags: javascript, function, object

Given:

```
myChart = new ganttChart("chart1");

function ganttChart(gContainerID) {

    this.variable1 = "lol";
    this.variable2 = "hai dere";
    this.variable3 = "cometishian";

....
    this.gContainer = document.getElementById(gContainerID);
    this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gBar" + i + 
            "\" class=\"gBar\" onmousedown=\"gInitBarDrag(this)\">Hello</div>";
....
}
```

How would I make the function gInitBarDrag() defined inside the ganttChart class?  I don't want an exterior standalone function as it needs to reference things inside the object.

So for example, the function would be able to reference variable1/2/3 which are defined in a specific instance of the ganttChart object (you can have multiple chart objects).

Hope that makes sense!  EG:

```
function ganttChart(gContainerID) {

    this.variable1 = "lol";
    this.variable2 = "hai dere";
    this.variable3 = "cometishian";

....
    this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gBar" + i + 
            "\" class=\"gBar\" onmousedown=\"gInitBarDrag(this)\">Hello</div>";
....

    gInitBarDrag = function(thisGanttObject)
    {
        alert(thisGanttObject.variable2);
        // This line wont work because it doesn't know what ganttChart to reference!
    }

}
```

Comment: @Tom What does the `this` value point to?

Comment: @Tom What do you mean by "granttChart class"? granttChart is a function, and there are no classes in JavaScript, anyway.

Comment: I think you could try to attach an event instead of declaring it in the markup, and reference the function inside ganttChart. Most of the JS framework nowadays should have an API to attach events to DOM objects. I'm not posting an answer because I'm not able to try to code that right now. If this is not answered by the time I get home, I will try to get some working code for you.

Comment: @Tom Aha, it is a constructor function then?

Comment: I've rephrased it, yes the innerHTML part is part of the constructor for the object

Comment: @Sime: depends on your definition of class. If you think about it as "a class is a construct that is used as a blueprint (or template) to create objects of that class" (quoted from wikipedia), then yes, there are classes in JS. prototypejs for example have some functions to create classes.

Comment: For God's sake, please don't use escaped quotes when they're not needed! Instead of this: `eval("alert(\"Hello, World!\")");`, use  `eval("alert('Hello, World!')")`. Certainly, `eval` was just an example.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H I don't see that as a big deal, just a preference thing.

Comment: @wtaniguchi Your definition is flawed. It should go like so: "a class is an **distinct** construct... ". JavaScript does not have such a distinct construct. In JavaScript, a function can be used to achieve the functionality of a class, but that doesn't make it a class. ... If I can bark like a dog, that doesn't make me a dog.

Comment: @Tom Are you sure that you can write `this.gContainer.innerHTML` without and error being thrown. Because `gContainer` is not defined, and you cannot attach properties to undefined.

Comment: The ... is referencing about 500 lines of code I've excluded for simplicity.  gContainerID is passed into the function, and gcontainer is defined as document.getElementById("gContainerID") in initialisation.  When a ganttChart is created the user must specify a target div for it to be rendered inside.

Comment: @Sime Oh I see... if I can bark like a dog, walk like a dog, have the DNA of a dog, but people didn't call me dog in the first place, I'm not a dog. I agree there is no distinct construct for classes in JS, but it doesn't mean that "and there are no classes in JavaScript, anyway.".

Comment: @wtaniguchi JavaScript functions do not "have the DNA of a class". They cannot define access specifiers (private, protected, public), there are no abstract functions, or partial functions or even sealed functions. The class construct is more complex than a JavaScript function. The point is this: JavaScript functions can **emulate** some of the functionality of a class, but **not** all of its functionality.

Comment: @Sime OK, so your definition of class construct MUST have access specifiers, abstract members, partial functions, etc. Mine doesn't, and that's where we disagree.

Comment: @Tom Yes, the meaning is the same, but it makes the code **very hard** to read.

Comment: @wtaniguchi From the book *JavaScript: The definitive guide*: "JavaScript does not officially define or support classes". From Crockford's website: "It does not have classes, but it does have constructors which do what classes do". Of course, you can have your own definition of what a class is and isn't, but regarding terminology it's generally better to agree with the convention - in this case: that JavaScript doesn't have classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function gnattChart(gContainerID) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'gBar';
  div.className = 'gBar';

  //If you want to reference properties from the gnattChart object...
  //Use `self` where you'd normally use `this` in the handler function
  var self = this;

  div.onmousedown = function () {
    //contents of gInitBarDrag here...
  };

  //If you want the container to be emptied...
  this.gContainer.innerHTML = '';

  this.gContainer.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: +1 That should do it. (Although I prefer attaching event handlers using a library)

Comment: @Šime Vidas - It's so easy to get off on tangents when talking about Javascript isn't it. Just trying to keep things simple. I'd prefer it as well, luckily using the `onevent` DOMNode properties is 100% cross-browser and at least an order of magnitude better than inline event attributes, even if not completely ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gBar" + i + "\" class=\"gBar\" onmousedown=\"function(){ alert('here'); }\">Hello</div>";
```

Although, inline functions are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Sorry you miss my question point, the function needs to be able to access variables within the main ganttChart object

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will answer without testing it, and using prototypejs, but I'm sure you can workout the functions for yourself if you don't want to use a JS framework.

First, you will want to create your div using document.createElement instead of injecting HTML, something like this:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
// Set your div properly.
```

Then you will have to use document.appendChild to put your new div (variable d) in your page.
Now the "difficult" part: listen for mousedown events and act accordingly. You can do this by using Event.observe (prototypejs) AND bind (prototypejs) to bind your object to the listener, so you can use its variables (this.variable1, variable2, etc).

This will give a code somewhat like this:

```
function ganttChart(gContainerID) { 

this.variable1 = "lol"; 
this.variable2 = "hai dere"; 
this.variable3 = "cometishian"; 

// Create Element part (createElement, appendChild, etc).
var d = document.createElement("div");
// continue from here.


this.gInitBarDrag = function() 
{ 
    alert(this.variable2); 
}; 

$(d).observe("mousedown", this.gInitBarDrag.bind(this));

}
```

Some notes: bind and observe can be implemented somewhat easily without a JS framework.
This code is untested.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a function as a property of an object, then `this` points to the object:

var myObject = { foo: true, bar: function(){ if(this.foo){ doStuff(); }};

If `this` is used in a constructor function that returns an object, then `this` is bound to the new object that is returned. The way you're using `this` in the code you posted, `this` points to the global scope, which is one of the bad parts of Javascript.

So, here's how I would approach this:

```
function GanttChart(gContainerID) {
    var chart = {
    variable1: "lol",
    variable2: "hai dere",
    variable3: "cometishian",
    containerId: gContainerID,
    gInitBarDrag: function(){
        alert(this.variable2);
        }
    }
    return chart;
}
myChart = new GanttChart("chart1");
document.getElementById(myChart.containerId).innerHTML += "<div id=\"gBar" + i + "\" class=\"gBar\" onmousedown=\"myChart.gInitBarDrag();\">Hello</div>";
```

I changed the ganttChart function to be capitalized because by convention, constructor functions that return an object are capitalized.

Answer (score -1):

```
var gInitBarDrag = function(){
  ///function body here
};

function ganttChart(gContainerID) {
....

    this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gBar" + i + "\" class=\"gBar\" onmousedown=\"gInitBarDrag(this)\">Hello</div>";
....


}
```

Comment: Will that function be able to reference variables contained within the ganttChart object?

Comment: No...it will look for a global function called `gInitBarDrag`, find none, and throw an exception

Comment: copy pasting mistake. fixed it